# Firewall rules for router

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I have a OpenWRT router which have the following rules allowed from WAN:

[image]

Can I disable some/all of them to increase security? The router is for normal home use.

Comment: In the Wiki from openWRT you can read alot of what settings do what and which might increase security for you. I know its bad to post links but its also a little too much to copy. https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access and https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can drop these:
Allow-Ping (It won't reply to ping request from the internet to your router)
Allow-ICMPv6-Input and Allow-ICMPv6-Forward (Used for Ping requests on IPv6)
 I would really drop those.
In fact if you don't want/need IPv6 for your network or your ISP does not supply IPv6 yet (Not widely used enough yet). You can drop anything that has v6 in the Name.
Also, if you don't use VPN Tunneling
Drop The Last Two ( wan to lan esp protocol ) and the ( wan to lan upd 500 )
ESP is a authentication header added before the IP header that is used in such protocol as IPsec, and UDP 500 is also used in IPsec authentication in the 1st Phase, but I think you could get rid of them if you are using a VPN service from your PC to an external server, simple testing can verify this as you could always add them back.

As Per Additional Comment Questions:
IGMP is used in Video/Gaming Streaming Services and therefore suggested to be kept.
MLD is the IPv6 version of IPv4's IGMP (Does the same thing but with IPv6)
You can drop it if you are forgoing all IPv6 Support (Suggested)
As far as the DHCP Renew on IPv4 UDP 68, this is used in the event your ISP wants to send your router an IP Renewal Message (Forcing your Router to Release and Renew it's Public IP from the ISP (Very Very Rare, but does happen)
There is a Lease time on IP Addresses and if your router hits that time, it will release and renew the IP (Usually Resulting in the same IP as before anyway)
But there are cases in which an ISP is doing network maintenance (Reallocating IPs to a different Demographic / Loss of License for those Public IPs / Larger IP Scopes being implemented / Changing Routes or Gateways ) where they need to send out the message for routers to release and renew their IPs, in the case where your router rejects this (You remove this rule), your router will continue to keep the same IP on the same subnet with the same gateway until such time the lease time your router has is reset, or the route is rebooted, or you manually do it in the routers settings, which in turn could result in you having the same IP as someone else, or you then have no gateway, or you just loose all service, which is rectified by doing one of the options of reboot router or manually in the settings release and renew.

Comment: It won't really increase security though. Blocking ICMP usually just results in pain in the ass a few months later.

Comment: @grawity I know that sending a ICMP request without dest can take down a router but hasn't that been fixed yet? and why does it become a pain in the ass after a few months?

Comment: I am not sure why you say that, Blocking ICMP in my experience does increase security to some extent. Blocking external pings is always a good idea, especially for IPv6 where an ISP if they do provide it, and your router supports it, can provide IPv6 Address to your entire network, now your ISP knows all the devices on your network, and potentially others, and have the means to access them.

Comment: @asmith Thank you, could you explain others, such as why I need to open MLD and DHCP for WAN? I do use VPN client on my computers, but only for connecting to servers outside, that need to open ports to WAN? If I block everything on a computer firewall it will still able to use DHCP or VPN, can't I do this on router?

Comment: I had to do a little light reading, but I found all this out, MLD can go if you want to get rid of IPv6 Support ( Which I suggest ), but "Allow-IGMP" should stay. I will update the above info with the relevant explanation. As far as you asking about the DHCP for udp 68 from WAN, this is needed in the event that your ISP sends out a renew IP address message to routers (Very Very Rare, but does happen).  And the eps and udp 500 should be safe for removal, but this can easily be tested if you need them by connecting to your vpn with them gone, and put them back if needed, I will give more info.

Comment: Updated with Relevant info, let me know if you need more

Comment: @asmith Thank you. I just tried disabling every rules, and the network is still fine. Will the router still working if ISP use ipv6? Or do I have to add those rules back when ipv6 is implemented in the future?

Comment: @Sam Yes, until IPv4 is complete phased out, I don't know of any ISP that forces IPv6 on their customers unless you are at a Tier 1 or Tier 2 Network of which Datacenters, Backbone Fiber Networks and Very Large Companies or ISP's themselves are apart of.